# How to create static sidebar on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, fixed, sidebar

I'm junior web designer and currently working on wordpress based website (modifying theme for local house clearance company).

The owners of the website want the sidebar to be fixed, so even when the user scroll down the page, the right sidebar (Our Services Menu) will always stay above the fold.

I tried so many CSS solutions but nothing works. Please [have a look](http://gorubbishgo.co.uk/house-clearance-london/) at the page in question.

I will be very grateful if you help me to fix this sidebar, because I'm desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ok friend you need to open your **functions.php** in your theme
2. Somewhere in your functions.php find `wp_enqueue_script('somename')`  there will be probably more than one of these and 'somename' is just an example and it will probably look something like this `wp_enqueue_script( 'some-boring-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/some-boring-name.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true' );`
3. After all of these add your own script like so `wp_enqueue_script('do-fixed-sidebar' get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/do-fixed-sidebar', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );`
4. It should look like this:

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script( 'some-boring-name', get_template_directory_uri() . 'some-boring-name.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'some-boring-name2', get_template_directory_uri() . 'some-boring-name2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'do-fixed-sidebar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/do-fixed-sidebar.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' );<--this will be your included do-fixed-sidebar.js file-->
   ```
5. You see `/js/do-fixed-sidebar.js` part in `wp_enqueue_script()`?

It means that you **NEED** to **create an empty folder** called ***js*** in your theme (if your theme does not have it)

6. To be on the safe side now your ***theme FOLDER structure*** should look like this (this is obviusly just an example):

   - index.php
   - style.css
   - single.php
   - author.php
   - all-other-files.php
   - js `<--this your empty folder -->`
7. Open text editor and create a new file and call it **`do-fixed-sidebar.js`**
8. Add following code to your `do-fixed-sidebar.js` and save it.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   var stickySidebar = $('.wpb_content_element').offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function() {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickySidebar) {
       $('.wpb_content_element').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        $('.wpb_content_element').removeClass('fixed');
    }  
    });

    });
   ```
9. Upload this file to your js folder in your theme.
10. We are NOT done yet... Find `style.css` in your theme and add this code:

    ```
    .fixed{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;<--this will probably need some adjusting maybe 45px...-->
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
    }
    ```

    11. Whoa you are done!! :)

Comment: Thank you Dejo Dekic, you have saved my day.

Comment: No problem, glad to help  :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for create custom sidebar in wordpress, use "register_sidebar" hook in function.php

register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'wpb' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'The main sidebar appears on the right on each page except the front page template', 'wpb' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

Now you can use this sidebar in any files of theme. you need to use this "dynamic_sidebar" for calling sidebar.

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```